# Установка модуля pthreads php Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, php7

Пытался установить composer
Ввожу команду php composer.phar install и выдает следующую ошибку

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-pthreads >=3.1.7dev is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's pthreads extension.
```

Пробовал установить pthreads так
pecl install ptreads

выдает следующее

```
checking for ZTS... configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
```

ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pthreads/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed

Помогите установить модуль

Comment: вам вроде пишут про включение`pthreads.so` в `php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

Комментарий оставить не могу, так что пишу тут. Рекомендую почитать https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/issues/584
Если кратко, то содержание ответа сводится:

```
sudo apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-zts
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zts php7.0-zts-dev
```

После этого

```
sudo  pecl install pthreads
```

У меня отработало без ошибок.